# Docker Compose Nginx within container unable to use public address of same container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, devops

I'm unable to curl/wget within the container with public IP address

nGinX

```
server {
  listen 3001;
  listen [::]:3001;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}

server {
  listen 3002;
  listen [::]:3002;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web;
  }
}
```

docker-compose

```
services:
  api:
    image: api
    container_name: api
    build: ./api
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker-network

  web:
    image: web
    container_name: web
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker-network

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"

    networks:
      - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Within the container:

`docker ps`

`docker exec -it web bash`

`wget example.com` -> response 200 works fine

`wget <public ip address of my server>:3001` -> connection timed out

Can anyone help in understanding how can we do an http/curl/wget call from inside the container to another container via public call? This is useful in case of Server Side Rendering where we need to fetch data inside `web` from `api`

Comment: `docker exec -it proxy bash` and then `wget/curl http://api` to make sure your api is actually listen on 80 port?

Comment: Proxy is listening on port 80. http://api:3001 works but not with public IP

Comment: but your ngnix config says `location / {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }` meaning it is going to proxy what it got on 3001 toward `api:80` because 80 is a default for http.
by the way your docker-compose yaml, looks just fine and should work. that is why i am looking into nginx config.

Comment: I tried without nGinX and inside container if I do wget with public IP address it is still unable to resolve. An example here: https://www.codemochi.com/blog/2019-07-10-prisma-2-nextjs-docker "docker-compose handles networking for us so we don't have to know what the actual IP address of the backend container is within the docker network- we can simply refer to it by a DNS name which is our container name, and docker takes care of the networking for us."

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was using Ubuntu on DigitalOcean, however just using CentOS solves the problem!